# ActiveMQ - handle connection, session, producer and concumer opon failover

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, failover

I do use failover transport feature by using the following pattern in the broker URL

```
failover:(tcp://host:port)
```

Init code goes as follow:

```
factory = new PooledConnectionFactory(BROKER_URL);
connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.start();
```

the put message code looks more or less like this:

```
session = connection.createSession( false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );
Destination destQueue = new ActiveMQQueue(queue);
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destQueue);
TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage(message);
producer.send(msg);
```

When a failover occurs -

```
[org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport] Transport (broker) failed, reason:  , attempting to automatically reconnect: java.net.SocketException: recv failed: Connection aborted by peer

and got reconnected after
[org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport] Failed to connect to [broker] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
08:55:29,596 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport] Successfully reconnected to broker
```

do I have to reinitiate a connection? Or to be more specific, do I have to do anything with the connection object to be able to produce/consume message after the failover?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the failover transport is to handle the reconnection for you.  The logs you've shown indicate a successful reconnect cycle where the transport has continued to retry to connect to a broker and eventually did so.